# Programmatically starting 6 servers and manipulating Gnome Terminal

Tags: linux, bash, gnome-terminal

I would like to make a script ( bash ) that will programmatically

1. start gnome-termal with 6 tabs each with its own title
2. start a different command in each tab
3. delay starting server 5 until sever 4 has been running for about
   1 minute
4. change the title of the gnome terminal to "My Servers"
5. switch tabs to the Server 4 tab

I would like to do all of this with double clicking on the file, without a dialog box ( RHEL 6 ) coming up to ask me if I want to display or run the file.

Googling around I got this far, but I could use some help with the rest:

```
gnome-terminal                                 \
--tab -t "Server 1"   -e commandStartServer1   \
--tab -t "Server 2"   -e commandStartServer2   \
--tab -t "Server 3"   -e commandStartServer3   \
--tab -t "Server 4"   -e commandStartServer4   \
--tab -t "Server 5"   -e commandStartServer5   \
--tab -t "Server 6"   -e commandStartServer6   \
```

Comment: Check http://superuser.com/questions/198015/open-gnome-terminal-programmatically-and-execute-commands-after-bashrc-was-execu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can just help you with the dialog box. Create a .desktop file, that will run you executable script. You can find a quick introduction to .desktop files [here](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en) or take a look at one of the files in /usr/share/applications.

As for the rest of the questions please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896882/open-gnome-terminal-programmatically-and-execute-commands-after-bashrc-was-execu/3902909#3902909) question.

Comment: That seems to have worked, at the second link you quoted what does the variable BASH_POST_RC mean?

Comment: I successfully used the method at the second link you posted, thank you.  I noticed that using that technique the command strings don't get put into the terminal or the history, just executed.  Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: if nothing else works, you could always add this command: echo 'command' >>~/.bash_history