# Make OS X Terminal commands I type BOLD

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, bash, terminal

I'd like to make commands I've typed (input) into terminal stand out from all the output.

For example:

imac:~ buster$ **chmod -R g-w myfolder**
 
imac:~ buster$ **cd myfolder**
imac:myfolder buster$ **ls -l**
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   9 root  admin   306 Apr 20  2010 bin
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  admin   238 Apr 20  2010 include
drwxr-xr-x  73 root  admin  2482 May 18 17:16 lib
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  admin   204 Apr 20  2010 man
imac:myfolder buster$ **echo Go Giants!**
Go Giants!

bold jumps to mind but I'd accept a color or even highlighting the whole line...

I'm sure there's a way to do this but it's not obvious to me...

thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` (see Gilles' comment below) and add the following lines:

```
BOLD="\[\033[1m\]"
OFF="\[\033[m\]"
PS1="${OFF}\u@\h:\w \$${BOLD}"
PS2="> ${BOLD}"
trap 'echo -ne "${OFF}" > $(tty)' DEBUG
```

Move the `${BOLD}` around to make part of the prompt also bold. If the prompt itself should not be colored, you need the `${OFF}` prefix in `PS1`, otherwise empty lines (pressing enter without having something written) will make the following prompt bold (credits to @Jay, thanks again!)

This adds a debug trap to turn bold format off, so it's quite a hack. [Credits](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#Different_colors_for_text_entry_and_console_output) (works without group tty on OS X though).

> This is a bit of a hack, so use it at your own risk.

Only setting your `PS1`/`PS2` prompts to bold would be easier and just as visible:

```
BOLD="\[\033[1m\]"
OFF="\[\033[m\]"
PS1="${BOLD}\u@\h:\w \$${OFF}"
PS2="${BOLD}>${OFF} "
```

Comment: Not `~/.bash_profile`, but `~/.bashrc` (or both, if you don't source `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile`). These settings need to be set for each interactive instance of bash, and `.bash_profile` is read only by login shells.

Comment: Thanks, will edit my answer. I have no `bashrc`, so I used what was there.

Comment: @Gilles: [An exception to the terminal window guidelines is Mac OS X’s Terminal.app, which runs a login shell by default for each new terminal window, calling .bash_profile instead of .bashrc. Other GUI terminal emulators may do the same, but most tend not to.](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html)

Comment: When i press <Enter> at an empty prompt, the new prompt is bold. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: @Jay: I'd have to research it. Is there a reason you're doing this, or just because it's possible?

Comment: I figured it out, put an ${OFF} at the front: PS1="${OFF}\u@\h:\w \$${BOLD}"

Comment: @Jay Aaah, of course. I'll edit my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel: Regarding `.bashrc` vs `.bash_profile`, the document you cite is mostly correct. (The one mistake I spotted was that it gives an example with `PATH` being set in `.bashrc`, but that should be `.bash_profile`.) Basically the only sane configuration is for `.bash_profile` to source `.bashrc`, as in the example given. See also [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](http://superuser.com/questions/183870).

Comment: To answer your previous question, I do press <Enter> at an empty prompt ever now and then. Sometimes gunk characters end-up in there somehow. Sometimes the prompt gets displayed at the end of the previous line instead of on its own line. I press enter to fix it.

Comment: @Daniel: There shouldn't be an underscore in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: There are still a few problems with this. Pressing the up arrow a few times causes the terminal to think the first 3 characters of the command are part of the prompt, and it won't let you remove them. Also, the list of matches you get when typing part of a file name then <Tab>, gets printed in bold.

Comment: @Jay Resizing the window also colors the prompt like the command. It's quite easy to break this, actually -- mine and your second issue are when the shell (re)writes something without hitting PS1 or Enter. This is probably why this is a hacky approach as written in the answer, with a non-hacky alternative provided. But it's the best I could come up with, and I'm not seeing that many better answers (yet). Let's hope someone smarter than me can figure this out.

Comment: @Jay Could you try to reproduce the "first three characters" issue again? I think I fixed it, but my up-arrow is a different command anyway and I can't find where I changed it right now.

Comment: If I use the up arrow four times in a row, to go through the command history, then the first 3 characters of the old command becomes part of the prompt, and there is no way to remove them. I can't delete them with the backspace key.

Comment: @Jay not for me, must be something else. I even reset my `inputrc` so I get the default up-arrow behavior. Sorry.

Comment: what does the trap "hack" in the first example do exactly? I'm not much of a BASH expert (obviously). I can sorta surmise the turning on and off of BOLD codes w/in the 2 main prompts...but not sure what trap/debug mean here.

Comment: @Meltemi: "hack" means I'm using a debugging facility in a way it probably shouldn't be used. `trap` is a bash buildin, so I'll refer you to the [bash man page](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/documentation/bash/bash.html), just search for `trap [-lp] [arg] [sigspec ...]` in there and you see what it does. Short version is: "If a sigspec is DEBUG, the command arg is executed after every simple command (see SHELL GRAMMAR above).". Means whenever a command was entered, we send the `OFF` format string to the [filename of the current TTY](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x721.html).

Answer (score 2):

I had a little trouble with the solutions here while using El Capitan (esp. in iTerm2 but in plain old Terminal as well). I got two sorts of errors:

1. The ability to delete my bash prompt entirely by just pressing space then backspace
2. Unwanted characters finding their way into my bash output, e.g. the input `pwd` would result in

   ```
   \[\]/Users/home/Directory
   ```

   or in

   ```
   \e[0m/Users/home/Directory
   ```

I propose the following solution, which is really just more of the same.

```
    BOLD="\033[1m"
    OFF="\033[m"
    PS1="${OFF}\u@\h :${BOLD}"
    PS2="> ${BOLD}"
    trap 'echo -ne "${OFF}" > $(tty)' DEBUG
```

Comment: Nice job! Just a few minor differences, but I'm glad you discovered a way for this to work with El Captain.