# Where's .bashrc for root?

Tags: linux, root, bashrc

I know it's not best practice, but on my dev system I login as root. What's the equivalent of the .bashrc file so I can alias some functions?

I've found the `/etc/bash.bashrc` & `/etc/bash.bashrc.local` but I'm not sure where to plop my commands.

Running x86_64 SUSE.

thanks, mjb.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Probably best to put them in ~/.bashrc .   It seems root doesn't get the normal ones by default in some distros, but you just `cp /etc/skel/.bash* ~` to fix that.

Comment: There we go --- I didn't know about the `skel` directory. Do you happen to know if that's the default? If I edit it, will it work universally if the user doesn't have a `~/.bashrc` ?

Comment: @mjb That's where new accounts get their default home directory. The `useradd` tool copies files from there. It is otherwise not used. You can add and alter stuff in there if you want every newly created user to have a different set of files. Think of it as the new user home dir template.

Comment: It's worth noting that the `~` in `~/.bashrc` above points to the `HOME` of root which typically is set to `/root` after we logged in as root (`sudo su`). When logged in as root, use `~someuser` to point to the home of `someuser` (`/home/someuser`).

Answer (score 28):

How about the home dir of root that is /root/?

From some aspects, root is just another user (just better, and allowed more).
root has a home dir, but it is not like the other users in /home/, 
but simply /root/ so root:s .bashrc is therefore /root/.bashrc

The ones in /etc is system specific settings for all users, including root.

---

Thanks to grawity to point out that you can use ~root points to the root home dir, 
regardless of where it is.

You can test that with

```
$> echo  ~root
/root
```

So even thou /root will work on 99% on the systems out there ~root is probably more portable and will probably work on 100%.

```
~root/.bashrc
```

Comment: Sometimes it *is* in /home. It's best to use **`~root/.bashrc`** to refer to the file in root's homedir.

Comment: The root home directory isn't in /home because in some *nix systems, /home is on a separate partition from the system drive and is not necessarily mounted.

Comment: You highlight why I was so confused --- there is no /root/.bashrc on this build.

Comment: probably work on 100%, i almots completely understand

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `/root/.bashrc` try using `/root/.profile` — it's the same thing, just a different name.

Also, if you are using `su` to get into root it may not be reading the `.bashrc` or `.profile` 
– just issuing `su` will not run the login scripts. try doing

```
su -
```

Comment: I beg to differ that a profile and bashrc are "the same thing".

Comment: Works for ttylinux ver 14.1 [boomslang] , Linux kernel: 2.6.38.1

Comment: @Slhck if they aren't the same thing, can you explain the differences? I'm a noob

Comment: @Gabriel https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile

Answer (score 2):

TL/DR: `/etc/bashrc`

This file get's incorporated into your `~/.bashrc` as well as that of all other users including `root`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the `.bashrc` file for the root user should be there: `/root/.bashrc`
If it is not the case, you can copy the 2 following files into `/root`, then you can edit the `.bashrc` file as you want.

```
cp /etc/skel/.bash_profile /root
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /root
```

Answer (score 1):

The similar topic: [Why suse doesn't have .bash_profile or .bashrc for root user](https://superuser.com/questions/738570/why-suse-doesnt-have-bash-profile-or-bashrc-for-root-user)

SuSe use /etc/bash.bashrc file to manage the environment. It's not indicated to add configs on this file, becouse when the server get updated, you'll lost your personal configuration.

You can create an archieve named bash.bashrc.local on /etc. The system will load any instruction found on this file, and then search for the default conf and execute both.

```
# vi /etc/bash.bashrc.local
```

Have fun!

Comment: /etc/bash.bashrc for SuSE Linux

 PLEASE DO NOT CHANGE /etc/bash.bashrc There are chances that your changes  will be lost during system upgrades.  Instead use /etc/bash.bashrc.local  for bash or /etc/ksh.kshrc.local for ksh or /etc/zsh.zshrc.local for the zsh or /etc/ash.ashrc.local for the plain ash bourne shell  for your local settings, favourite global aliases, VISUAL and EDITOR variables, etc ...

Answer (score 0):

I looked here because on my (64-bit) Slackware 14.2, logging into root does most certainly NOT source /root/.bashrc. It DOES source /home/user/.bashrc on loggin to user account. 
There is no /etc/bash.bashrc, or any other bash files in /etc.
Nor is there any such directory as /etc/skel apparently, in slack.

Comment: It's always nice to see some links to documentation.