# Why suse doesn't have .bash_profile or .bashrc for root user

Tags: suse

I want to set few ALIAS commands on my Suse setup for root user.
I cant find .bashrc file for root user in /root.

Can i use /etc/profile for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just create a .bashrc file with the required aliases in `/root/.bashrc`. Bash will use this if it finds it.

Comment: Creating .bashrc is helpful do you know the purpose of /etc/profile can i change it for aliasing.

Answer (score -1):

To help, you can create an archieve named bash.bashrc.local on /etc. The system will load any instruction found on this file, and then search for the default conf and execute both.

/etc/bash.bashrc.local