# What's the difference between .profile and .bash_profile, and when do you configure which? (Mac)

Tags: linux, macos, mac, unix, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile)

What's the difference between `.profile` and `.bash_profile`, and when do you configure which?

I.e if I configure the `.bash_profile`, do I still need to configure `.profile`?

Comment: For Mac-specific questions I recommend https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 15):

Assuming `bash` is your default shell, the differences are described in the `bash` man page (`man bash`):

```
   When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as  a  non-interac-
   tive  shell  with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands
   from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading that file,
   it  looks  for  ~/.bash_profile,  ~/.bash_login,  and  ~/.profile, in that
   order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists  and
   is readable.  The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started
   to inhibit this behavior.
```

There is more detail in the man page that covers POSIX-shell compatibility mode, which is where `.profile` comes from.  Read the whole man page section for all the details.

Comment: in Ubuntu 18.04 opening an new Terminal window does not call `.profile` only `.bashrc` :(

Comment: To clarify, "reads and executes commands from the first one that exists", means it only runs the first of the 3 files it finds (so if all 3 existed, it would only run `~/.bash_profile`, which was not obvious to me (I assumed it would run all three).

Answer (score 5):

If you configure `.bash_profile`, you won't also need to configure `.profile`.

I like to keep my own aliases and commands in `.profile` so that if I mess up anything, I know that I can always delete the `.profile` without affecting the system at large or other applications that modify `.bash_profile` (like MacPorts).

To use a `.profile`, you may need to include the line `source ~/.profile` in your `.bash_profile` so that the `.profile` file is read (see Ned Deily's answer).

Answer (score 2):

.profile is executed by bash when you get a normal shell process -- e.g. you open a terminal tool.
.bash_profile is executed by bash for login shells -- so this is when you telnet/ssh into your machine remotely for instance.
For instance if you ssh remotely into a machine (let's say you open an X Terminal) you will get initially .bash_profile executed. If in that XTerminal you type "xterm" and spawn another X Terminal, then .profile will be executed for the second instance of XTerminal.
The files reside in your home directory (~). If I'm not mistaking by default they both execute ~/.bashrc so you can edit that to configure common settings/variables for both login and non login shells (e.g setting PATH, some aliases/shortcuts etc). You might want occasionally to configure certain things differently for these 2 but I have never encountered that need -- however, the possibility is there.

Comment: in Ubuntu 18.04 opening an new Terminal window does not call `.profile`?

Answer (score 1):

for the fast and simple config (where you don't want complicate things) simply configure everything in your ~/.profile. Only when you run into some troubles (but probably will never) learn more about the .bash_login or .bash_profile ;)

I'm on OS X too, and never needed .bash_profile or .bash_login and using only .profile, but your mileage may vary...