# When does mac/ubuntu use .bash_profile and/or .bashrc?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile)

Are they both the same type of file in terms of setting the bash terminal settings, and if no .bash_profile exists then it uses .bashrc?

Also, from within my .bash_profile, can I split my configurations into other files and load them from INSIDE my .bash_profile like:

```
..
source .some_file
soource .some_file2
..
```

I want to be able to share my .bash_profile file, yet have some private settings kept secret.

I also want to use the same setup for ubuntu and mac, so not sure if things are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

`.bash_profile` is read if your Bash is called as a login shell, `.bashrc` for non-login shells.

To split your configuration you can use something like

```
if [ -d ~/.bash.d ]; then
    for i in ~/.bash.d/*.sh; do
        if [ -r $i ]; then
            . $i
        fi
    done
    unset i
fi
```

That loads all `*.sh` files in `~/.bash.d/` for which you have read permission.

Comment: I believe it's actually both read and execute permissions.

Comment: @Hello71: No, the snippet above only checks for *read* using `-r`, and *sources* the file instead of executing it.