# Why is there a .bash_profile and .bashrc, they seem to do the same thing?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [When does mac/ubuntu use .bash_profile and/or .bashrc?](https://superuser.com/questions/283253/when-does-mac-ubuntu-use-bash-profile-and-or-bashrc)
>   [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile)

I loaded up ubuntu on a vm on my windows computer, and my .bash_profile doesn't seem to load when I open up a terminal (I have to source .bash_profile to get it to work).

Do some systems load .bashrc by default, while others (like Mac osx) loads .bash_profile?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer to an earlier question of yours](https://superuser.com/questions/171035/profile-or-bash-profile) actually already also answers this: depending on how your `bash` is invoked, it reads different files. For a detailed guide, see [this web page](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html).

The first few comments on [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/204003/make-os-x-terminal-commands-i-type-bold/204014#204014) might also help you.