# Where do I initialize my environment when the shell loads?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I am using bash shell and have content in my `.bashrc`.

When `Terminal` app opens (on my mac), this file however is not initialized.

I am always able to manually `. ./.bashrc`, however i'd rather not have to do it.

What is the name of the file which, would either initialize my environment for me, or the file where i can put my customization options in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the general case you can use `~/.profile`

---

Also note (from the `bash` manpage):

> When bash is invoked as an **interactive login shell**, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

and:

> When an interactive shell that is **not a login shell** is started, bash reads and executes commands from `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`, if these files exist. This may be inhibited by using the `--norc` option. The `--rcfile` file option will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`.

For a more complete question/answer, see:

- [What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)
- [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile)