# Confused about setting environment variables

Tags: terminal, debian, environment-variables

I've been trying to set some environment variables for hours and it does not work *grml* Here the setting:

I use Debian 6 and there the terminal from the desktop. In this window, I type "su" to login as root. There are two other users: myname and globus. Now I want to set the JAVA_HOME, ANT_HOME and PATH variable for ALL THREE USERS (root, myname, globus). Concerning to this [article](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980) I edited the /home/myname/.profile and /home/globus/.profile added this:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr"
ANT_HOME="/lib/apache-ant-1.8.2"
```

Now, when I login as globus (open Terminal from desktop and type "su globus") and echo $ANT_HOME, I get "/usr" and not the value above... beside this, I only get a "$" and the beginning of the line and not something like "root@mydebian: /current/path".

This is the content of my .profile:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin;
export JAVA_HOME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user's ~/.profile is read by a login shell. Executing "su *user*" effectively changes your identity to *user* by starting a shell as *user*; you haven't logged in as *user*. To log in as *user*, execute "su -l *user*".

Comment: "-l" solved my problems :-) Thank you! I didn't get the difference between "login shell" and "other shell"... and how to set this for the root user? When I use "su" only. Or should I use "su -l root"?

Comment: I guess it depends on what task you wish to perform as *user* and how much of *user*'s identity and environment you want to assume. If you just need to perform some task as a different user, use "su". If you need to perform some task in another user's environment, use "su -l".

Answer (score 1):

That should work:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr;
export JAVA_HOME
ANT_HOME=/lib/apache-ant-1.8.2;
export ANT_HOME
```

You don't need to have that in separate lines, I just like to keep it that way so I can add those to the `PATH` later, for example:

```
GRAILS_HOME=/Users/werner/Library/grails;
export GRAILS_HOME
export PATH=$GRAILS_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: no, unfortunately not :-(

Comment: You'd need to run `source /home/myname/.profile` to reload the settings immediately. Does that work?

Comment: With "-l" it worked... nevertheless I upvoted your answer because of your work, thank you!

Comment: @strauberry Oh, okay. Maybe your case was too specific :) See here for an explanation on login shell vs. non-login shell: http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html