# Command shortcut to ./startup.sh Tomcat

Tags: linux, tomcat

Every time I need to start or stop Tomcat, I am navigating to:

```
 /Tomcat_Dir/bin
```

and once I am in the folder I enter:

```
./Startup.sh
```

And to stop the server, I navigate to the same directory and enter:

```
 ./Shutdown.sh
```

I was wondering if there was a way in Linux to alias the above described process, so that from any location in the filesystem, I can simply type in something like

`StartTomcat` or `StopTomcat` to perform the Startup and Shutdown of the web-server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need to navigate to these directories. Just use the full paths instead:

```
/Tomcat_Dir/bin/Startup.sh
/Tomcat_Dir/bin/Shutdown.sh
```

With those, you can create an alias, as you said:

```
alias StartTomcat='/Tomcat_Dir/bin/Startup.sh'
alias StopTomcat='/Tomcat_Dir/bin/Shutdown.sh'
```

Add these lines to your `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`, or `~/.bashrc` (whichever you're using – [what is the difference?](https://superuser.com/q/183870/48078)), restart the shell, and you're done.

Comment: This is great. I had to use sudo `alias StartTomcat='sudo /Tomcat_Dir/bin/Startup.sh'`

Answer (score 3):

I know of three easy options -

1) You can add the `/Tomcat_Dir/bin` to your PATH.

open your .bashrc and edit/add the following

> PATH=$PATH:/Tomcat_Dir/bin/

2) Add links to the startup and shutdown scripts in you bin directory.

> ln -s /Tomcat_Dir/bin/Startup.sh /bin/tom_start.sh
>
> ln -s /Tomcat_Dir/bin/Shutdown.sh /bin/tom_stop.sh

3) Alias the startup and shutdown scripts.

> alias Tomstart='/Tomcat_Dir/bin/Startup.sh'
>
> alias Tomstop='/Tomcat_Dir/bin/Shutdown.sh'