# Custom command in terminal with a variable

Tags: linux, terminal

Redhat Linux Enterprise

Editing a terminal profile -- Run a custom command instead of my shell
Custom command:

```
tail -3000f /home/user1/folder/$PROJECT/folder2/folder3/text.log
```

When I save it and relaunch, I get:

```
tail: cannot open `/home/user1/folder/$PROJECT/folder2/folder3/text.log' for reading
```

When I copy this path directly to another terminal, tailing works fine. Is the custom command auto escaping the $PROJECT variable?

Comment: What are the access rights? (output of ls-l /home/user1/folder/$PROJECT/folder2/folder3/text.log)

Comment: -rw-r--r-- "4 more to go"

Comment: What does that "4 more to go" mean?
More improtant question is - what do you want to accomplish with this modification?

Comment: (4 more to go was just SO's character minimum for comments)  I want to be able to tail a log upon terminal startup. The path of the file to tail changes from project to project.

Comment: Ok, so where does the command entered in "Editing a terminal profile -- Run a custom command instead of my shell Custom command:" end up? Is it in the ~/.bashrc file?

Comment: Not sure -- been looking for that too

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are using gnome-terminal, and that the "custom command" you mention is the custom command which gnome-terminal will run instead of the default shell (usually bash).

Gnome-terminal is a terminal emulator. It has no knowledge of the concept of variables or variable expansion. That is why, if told to execute some string containing `$PROJECT`, it will do just that, it will not expand `$PROJECT`. Variable expansion is the work of the shell.

Read the wikipedia articles about [terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) and [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) to better understand the difference between a terminal and a shell.

If I am correct with my assumption, that you are running gnome-terminal with a custom command, then you should use this custom command instead:

```
bash -c "tail -3000f /home/user1/folder/$PROJECT/folder2/folder3/text.log"
```

This will tell gnome-terminal to execute bash with some arguments. The arguments will tell bash to execute the command `tail` with some arguments. Only this time, before executing `tail`, bash will expand the variable `$PROJECT` before executing.

Note that starting bash using the parameter `-c` will cause bash to not read the initialisation files (`.bashrc` and/or `.profile`). If `$PROJECT` is defined in one of those files then the above command might fail because `$PROJECT` will expand to nothing.

You can force bash to read the initialisation files by using the `-l` parameter:

```
bash -l -c "tail -3000f /home/user1/folder/$PROJECT/folder2/folder3/text.log"
```

Note that bash has this concept of "login shell" and "interactive shell" with some implications on what initialisation files are read. For more explanation of the difference read the following question and answers: [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980).

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting that command in a file and sourcing the file or making it executable and executing it like a script? It's possible the environment isn't being passed to the script. Is $PROJECT an environment variable (export'ed or setenv'ed) or is it a variable in your current shell?

If you're using bash or sh, you can try `export $PROJECT` or if you're using csh/tcsh you can try `setenv PROJECT=(the value of $PROJECT)`

Comment: exported -- i take the /home/user1/.../$PROJECT/... into another terminal and it runs fine.

Comment: it might be that my profile is not being sourced properly on launch of this terminal window...

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess - try:

```
tail -3000f /home/user1/folder/${PROJECT}/folder2/folder3/text.log
```

It uses variable written as ${PROJECT} instead of $PROJECT. Unfortunately I am not able to test it.

Comment: Nope; it now prints out .../${PRJ_NAME}/... :)