# shell environment setup for virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper

Tags: bash, zsh, systemd, gdm, virtualenv

The question is about shell setup for [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), an extension to [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) ([python guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)).

Similar questions had been asked many times but with a lot with different answers:

- [Environment variables in bash_profile or bashrc?](https://superuser.com/questions/409186/environment-variables-in-bash-profile-or-bashrc)
- [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile?answertab=active#tab-top)

Which is the *"best"* way to trigger environment setup and function definition script, considering several possible options:

1. **~/.profile**
2. **~./.bash_profile**, **~/.zprofile**
3. **~./bash_login**, **~./zlogin** (esoteric option)
4. **~/.bashrc**, **~/.zshrc**

The [virtualenvwrapper guide](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#shell-startup-file) states:

*"Add three lines to your shell startup file (.bashrc, .profile, etc.) to set the location where the virtual environments should live"*

Before considering available options, it is important to consider possible *"Use-Cases"*:

- terminal (console) login (without X, locally)
- ssh remote login (interactive)
- ssh remote command execution (non interactive)
- after a "graphical" login (GDM), opening a terminal (gnome-terminal)
- directly in DE (Gnome), via "desktop" file Exec invocation
- indirectly invoked from xclient (e.g. emacs subprocess)
- stated as cron job for the user
- registered as systemd service (or socket) for non-root user
- indirectly started by a service subprocess (e.g. httpd CGI)

In order to support X graphical login, the only way to set the path is via **~/.profile**, that gets sources by **/etc/gdm/Xsession**, after **/etc/profile**

While this is the best place for path and environment setting, it fails to define correctly virtualenvwrapper functions (*"workon"*)

The reason is that Xsession is executed under POSIX **/bin/sh** shell,
that is not supported by virtualenvwrapper [(bash, zsh, ksh support)](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#supported-shells)

Some distro adopted **dash** as POSIX shell, while other still rely on POSIX-mode bash invocation.

See

- https://github.com/brainsik/virtualenv-burrito/issues/8

for non bash/zsh/ksh exclusion.

---

In X logins, using **~/.profile** for (manual) environment settings works:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
export ENV_NAME='myvirtualenv'
export VIRTUAL_ENV="$WORKON_HOME/$ENV_NAME"
export PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
unset PYTHON_HOME
```

the virtualenvwrapper function definition does not work;

```
source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`
```

---

A alternative could be to put everything in **~/bashrc**

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
export ENV_NAME='myvirtualenv'
source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`

workon $ENV_NAME
```

But this DOES NOT WORK also:

1. X (gnome-shell) does not get initialized, so .desktop files exec command with the "system" environment, not the virtual one.
2. the environment set by some process (emacs) is destroyed by ~/.bashrc override

An example:

- https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/538

---

A better option could be a mixed solution (not so cool ...)

In **~/.profile**, manual environment setting

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
export ENV_NAME='myvirtualenv'
export VIRTUAL_ENV="$WORKON_HOME/$ENV_NAME"
export PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
unset PYTHON_HOME
```

In **~/.bash_profile** or **~/.zprofile**, include POSIX  profile and function definition:

```
[ -f ~/.profile ] && source ~/.profile
[ -f `which virtualenvwrapper.sh` ] && source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`
```

In gnome-terminal, enabling the **"login-shell"** option, the *"workon"* functions gets defined.

For remote execution it is possible to trigger profile inclusion in this way:

```
ssh localhost bash --login -c env
```

Maybe something similar could be done for *systemd* and *cron* invocation.

See:

- https://gist.github.com/BerraDev/22a7216a5e1e16bcc2c2

---

All this configuration stuff looks ugly and hard to maintain.
Is it possible a better solution ?

Comment: maybe also **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** should be prepended in **~/.profile**

Answer (score 2):

But, after all, why should virtualenv be active in global **gnome-shell** context ?

This would surely break all **system-level** python application installed.

So the **only** safe way to start a virtualenv application is to start from a terminal shell

Probably it is safer to *activate* environment in the **~/.bash_profile** **~/.zprofile**, enabling **login-shell** option in terminal.

The alternative setting, using **~/.bashrc**, should be avoided because it can cause problems in subshells.

So,

- enable the login-option
- start the terminal (or bash/zsh --login in xterm ...)
- *"workon"*
- then start emacs (server) from the terminal shell.

---

To run a virtualenv application from *gnome-shell*, the desktop file must exec a dedicated wrapper script that source env **activate** before execution.

For a generic *wrapper* (similar to ruby *'bundle exec'* and rvm stuff), see:

- https://gist.github.com/datagrok/2199506

Maybe a 're-hash' is required ...

- https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/develop/virtualenv_embedded/activate.sh#L76

Comment: Having two shells (bash,zsh), one can point **bash** to *"system-wide"* virtualenv in **/usr/local/lib/pythonenvs** and **zsh** to *"user"* virtualenv in **~/.virtualenvs**. Useful to test deployment. The same configuration could be applied to RVM