# How does the .profile file work if I fork a process?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, zsh

Lets say I open vlc or gimp on startup, but those commands don't return until the program closes. Does it just let a bash interpreter run indefinitely until they close or does it run and immediately kill the process unless I nohup or something? What's the appropriate way to startup these applications?

Comment: Append an `&` to the program call in the shell script, and look into your desktop environment's preferred way to launch applications on login.

Answer (score 0):

The .profile is read when bash starts. Starting another program from the shell does nothing to the .profile file.

Have a look at this: [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980)