# How do I modify my Git Bash profile in Windows?

Tags: windows, bashrc, .bash-profile, git-bash

I'm using Git Bash on Windows 7 and would like to set up Bash profile aliases such as `alias gs='git status'` to make my life easier. How can I do this?

Comment: [Obligatory git alias joke](https://twitter.com/chris__martin/status/420992421673988096?lang=en)

Comment: @StuperUser can't believe no one upvoted that yet!

Answer (score 155, accepted):

When you open up your Git Bash, you should be in your home directory by default.
Now create the **.bashrc** file (if on Windows 7 the file should be named **.bashrc.**).

If you're not in the home directory, change into it by typing:

> cd

and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. cd, without any other parameters listed after, will always return the home directory.

You can create the file by typing:

> touch .bashrc

Then edit it with Vim or you could try doing it with some Windows editor, but I don't recommend it, because of some text formatting issues.

> vim .bashrc

Change to Insert Mode by hitting the <kbd>i</kbd> key.

Add your alias by typing:

> alias gs='git status'

Exit the insert mode by hitting the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

Save and close your file by typing the following <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

<kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> will only save your file.

<kbd>:</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>!</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> will quit the editor without saving your file.

Finally, update the file to use your new changes by typing:

> source .bashrc

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know about .bashrc before, so your answer lead me to several sources, including http://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile, that agree that .bashrc is a better place to put aliases than .bash_profile.

Comment: This really helped! I love that you also supplied the additional commands to use VIM. It's not really the most friendliest editor. Much appreciated!

Comment: This gives me `WARNING: Found ~/.bashrc but no ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login or ~/.profile. This looks like an incorrect setup. A ~/.bash_profile that loads ~/.bashrc will be created for you.` (Git-2.11.0-64-bit)

Comment: How can I add a path in that file I tried: ´alias app='cd c:\mypath'´

Comment: FYI, no need to `touch` the file, `vi` will create it for you directly. Prevents you one line ;)

Comment: only the first time you open the git bash @aliopi. It's doing what it says, creating a .bash_profile file for you.

Answer (score 40):

You can put `.bash_profile` in your user directory: *C:\Users\<username>*.

You can also create some git-only aliases so you can do just `git st` for `git status` by adding these lines to *C:\Users\<username>\.gitconfig*:

```
[alias]
st = status
```

Some other useful aliases:

```
cm = commit -m
cma = commit -a -m
br = branch
co = checkout
df = diff
ls = ls-files
sh = stash
sha = stash apply
shp = stash pop
shl = stash list
mg = merge
ph = push -u
```

Comment: If aliases for Git commands are needed, editing the `.gitconfig` file is usually sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wasn't expecting to get two different but correct answers.

Comment: For me, `.bash_profile` *wasn't* in my windows home dir. but my roaming home dir (network admin imposed). The "correct" answer is "put `.bash_profile` in your *git bash* home dir", which you can find by going to `cd ~` then `pwd`

Answer (score 5):

My git version is git version 2.18.0.windows.1
It took me a while to figure out where the .bashrc was 
C:\Program Files\Git\etc ---> bash.bashrc
hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Simply (if you have .bashrc you will add aliases to the end of file):

```
cat >> ~/.bashrc
```

Paste or type a list of aliases. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and finally run:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Git Bash home directory, there should be a .gitconfig file. In this file you can add your aliases by adding `[alias]`. It should be something like below:

```
[alias]
st = status
co = checkout
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find your `~/.bashrc` file, you can add all aliases to your `~/.bash_profile` file.

For instance, to add an alias for a Git command (`git status`) simply add:

```
alias gs="git status"
```

In the same way you can add an alias for a Bash command (change directory path):

```
alias myd="cd ~/path to my directory"
```