# Choosing between .bashrc, .profile, .bash_profile, etc

Tags: unix, environment-variables

This is embarrassing, but after many years of using POSIX systems full time, I still have a hard time figuring out if a shell customization should go in `.bashrc`, `.profile`, or somewhere else. Not to mention some of the OS-specific config files like `.pam_environment`.

Yes, I know how to puzzle through the documentation and learn when each file is or isn't loaded. What I'm wondering is if anyone has every put together comprehensive guidelines for how to decide which file to put a given type of customization in.

Comment: this question should not be marked as duplicate the reason is .profile is not available in the added question.

Comment: Ans: http://serverfault.com/q/261802/270464

Answer (score 291):

TL;DR:

- `~/.bash_profile` should be super-simple and just load `.profile` and
  `.bashrc` (in that order)
- `~/.profile` has the stuff NOT specifically
  related to bash, such as environment variables (`PATH` and friends)
- `~/.bashrc` has anything you'd want at an interactive command line.
  Command prompt, `EDITOR` variable, bash aliases for my use

A few other notes:

- Anything that should be available to graphical applications OR to sh (or bash invoked as `sh`) MUST be in `~/.profile`
- `~/.bashrc` must not output anything
- Anything that should be available only to login shells should go in `~/.profile`
- Ensure that `~/.bash_login` does not exist.

Comment: +1, this allows `~/.profile` to correctly set environment for services like GDM/LightDM/LXDM which explicitly run /bin/sh.

Comment: My `.bashrc` outputs quite a lot of stuff, can you comment on that? In particular, where should I put the greeting output?

Comment: You deserve an upvote, this is how I do it, and it seems to be a sane way.

Comment: @Calimo: Make it only output stuff in interactive mode. You can test for it using `[[ $- == *i* ]]`, that is, looking for 'i' in the special `$-` variable. Of course, it only matters in the first place on systems where bash is compiled to read `.bashrc` in non-interactive mode. (That is, Debian but not Arch.) But it's a frequent cause of mysterious error messages when attempting to connect using `sftp` or `scp` or similar tools.

Comment: Now I've gotta know- why should .bash_login not exist? What does it do?

Comment: @tedder42: It does the same as `.bash_profile` and `.profile`. But bash only reads the first one out of three. Meaning, if you have a `.bash_login`, then both `.profile` and `.bash_profile` will be mysteriously ignored.

Comment: @grawity `bash` will load `.bash_profile` and not `.bash_login` if they both exist, according to the man page & the linked duplicate question. So it's inaccurate to say to that `.bash_login` will cause `.bash_profile` to be ignored.

Comment: In MacOS it seems like `.profile` will be ignored when starting a bash session if `.bash_profile` exist.

Comment: @grawity, Wtf? Who invented that sequence?

Answer (score 71):

Over the last few years, I've had a lot of time to waste, so I *have* researched this for a bit more than just 10 minutes. I have no idea if this is the best layout, it's just one that happens to work correctly in pretty much all cases.

The requirements:

- `~/.profile` must be compatible with any /bin/sh – this includes bash, dash, ksh, whatever else a distro might choose to use.
- Environment variables must be put in a file that is read by both console logins (i.e. a 'login' shell) and graphical logins (i.e. display managers like GDM, LightDM, or LXDM).
- There is very little point in having *both* `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile`. If the latter is missing, bash will happily use the former, and any bash-specific lines can be guarded with a check for `$BASH` or `$BASH_VERSION`.
- The separation between `*profile` and `*rc` is that the former is used for 'login' shells, and the latter every time you open a terminal window. However, bash in 'login' mode doesn't source `~/.bashrc`, therefore `~/.profile` needs to do it manually.

The *simplest* configuration would be:

- Have a `~/.profile` that sets all environment variables (except bash-specific ones), perhaps prints a line or two, then sources `~/.bashrc` if being run by bash, sticking to sh-compatible syntax otherwise.

  ```
  export TZ="Europe/Paris"
  export EDITOR="vim"
  if [ "$BASH" ]; then
      . ~/.bashrc
  fi
  uptime
  ```
- Have a `~/.bashrc` that performs any shell-specific setup, guarded with a check for *interactive mode* to avoid breaking things like `sftp` on Debian (where bash is compiled with the option to load `~/.bashrc` even for non-interactive shells):

  ```
  [[ $- == *i* ]] || return 0

  PS1='\h \w \$ '

  start() { sudo service "$1" start; }
  ```

---

However, there's also the problem that certain non-interactive commands (e.g. `ssh <host> ls`) skip `~/.profile`, but environment variables would be very useful to them.

- Certain distributions (e.g. Debian) compile their bash with the option to source `~/.bashrc` for such non-interactive logins. In this case, I've found it useful to move all environment variables (the `export ...` lines) to a separate file, `~/.environ`, and to source it from *both* `.profile` and `.bashrc`, with a guard to avoid doing it twice:

  ```
  if ! [ "$PREFIX" ]; then   # or $EDITOR, or $TZ, or ...
      . ~/.environ           # generally any variable that .environ itself would set
  fi
  ```
- Unfortunately, for other distributions (e.g. Arch), I haven't found a very good solution. One possibility is to use the (enabled by default) pam_env PAM module, by putting the following in `~/.pam_environment`:

  ```
  BASH_ENV=./.environ        # not a typo; it needs to be a path, but ~ won't work
  ```

  Then, of course, updating `~/.environ` to `unset BASH_ENV`.

---

Conclusion? Shells are a pain. Environment variables are a pain. Distribution-specific compile-time options are an *immense* pain in the ass.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph, but I prefer sourcing `.profile` and `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile` and keeping `.profile` clean.

Comment: @nyuszika7h: My `.profile` [is clean](https://github.com/grawity/dotfiles/blob/master/profile), thanks.

Comment: Note the comment re every time you open a window is the other way round for OSX

Comment: "There is very little point in having both `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile`": I disdagree. See Dan's answer for why.

Comment: @rubenvb Can you quote the relevant part? I think it's fine to have only a `.profile` and guard the `bash`-specific parts with conditionals.

Comment: _"sticking to sh-compatible syntax otherwise"_: a good point, but strictly speaking, the syntax `export EDITOR="vim"`  is _not_ sh-compatible. ( Although almost every `sh` implementation nowadays supports it, the "classic" `sh` syntax would be `EDITOR="vim" ; export EDITOR` -- see e.g. the list of `bash` differences [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Major-Differences-From-The-Bourne-Shell.html) )

Answer (score 50):

Have a look at this [excellent blog post by ShreevatsaR](http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/). Here's an extract, but go to the blog post, it includes an explanation for terms like "login shell", a flow chart, and a similar table for Zsh.

> For Bash, they work as follows. Read down the appropriate column. Executes A, then B, then C, etc. The B1, B2, B3 means it executes only the first of those files found.
>
> |  | Interactive login | Interactive non-login | Script |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | `/etc/profile` | A |  |  |
> | `/etc/bash.bashrc` |  | A |  |
> | `~/.bashrc` |  | B |  |
> | `~/.bash_profile` | B1 |  |  |
> | `~/.bash_login` | B2 |  |  |
> | `~/.profile` | B3 |  |  |
> | `BASH_ENV` |  |  | A |
> |  |  |  |  |
> | `~/.bash_logout` | C |  |  |

Comment: This is nice. It is important to note that usually `/etc/profile` calls `/etc/bash.bashrc`, and `~/.profile` calls `~.bashrc`. So effectively, `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` are being executed for Interactive Logins as well.

Comment: Note that some distributions seem to override this scheme (with strange consequences) - see e.g. my bugreport to opensuse here: https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1078124

Comment: Btw. at least with bash none of those files is being executed when the bash is being called via `/bin/sh`

Comment: @JepZ You're right, that's what the third column "Script" explains.

Comment: @Flimm Well, the column 'Script' describes what happens when you start a non-interactive script via **bash** (e.g. /bin/bash). However, if you start a script via **sh** (and /bin/sh is a symlink to /bin/bash) none of the above is executed (not even `BASH_ENV`). The related paragraph of the bash man page can be found by searching for `If  bash  is  invoked with the name sh`.

Comment: Huge thanks for the link - really excellent! - valuable the tables and diagrams!

Answer (score 26):

I offer you my "comprehensive" guidelines:

- Make `.bash_profile` and `.profile` load `.bashrc` if it exists, using e.g.

  `[ -r $HOME/.bashrc ] && source $HOME/.bashrc`
- Put everything else in `.bashrc`.
- Stop worrying.
- Every four years or so, spend ten minutes researching this very question before giving up and going back to "not worrying".

---

EDIT: Added scare quotes to "comprehensive" just in case anyone is tempted to believe it. ;)

Comment: Having both `.bash_profile` and `.profile` is a bit redundant; you only need the latter. You do need to make it /bin/sh-proof, though: `if [ "$BASH" ] && [ -r ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi`, as there are programs (namely gdm/lightdm) that manually source the file from a /bin/sh script. This also means that environment kept in `.bashrc` would be ineffective. Had to -1, since your "comprehensive" guidelines will not work on many systems, as I had found out the hard way several times.

Comment: No problem, I'd happily pay a -1 for an answer that is not merely tongue-in-cheek "comprehensive", and you've certainly earned that title.

Answer (score 2):

I gave up on trying to figure this one out and made one script (`~/.shell-setup`) which I source from all of the others.

This approach requires `~/.shell-setup` to have two features:

1. Only run once, even when sourced repeatedly (use [Include guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518584))
2. Don't generate any unwanted output (detect when output is ok)

#1 is pretty standard, although maybe not used much in shell scripts.

#2 is trickier.  Here's what I use in bash:

```
if [ "" == "$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING" -a "" == "$DESKTOP_SESSION" ]; then
    echo "Hello user!" # ... etc
fi
```

Unfortunately I don't remember how I came up with that, or why [detecting an interactive shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26676) wasn't sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

Put everything in `.bashrc` and then source `.bashrc` from `.profile`

From the bash man page (on OS X 10.9):

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.  This may be inhibited by using the --norc  option.   The  --rcfile file option will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of ~/.bashrc

The above text is why everything is put in `.bashrc`. However, there's a bit different behavior when you're dealing with a login shell. Again, quoting from the man page:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

`.profile` is read for login shells, but `.bashrc` is not. Duplicating all that stuff in `.bashrc` is bad™ so we need to source it in `.profile` in order for the behavior to remain consistent.

However, you don't want to source `.bashrc` from `.profile` unconditionally. Please see the comments and other answers for additional details.

Comment: -1, **DO NOT** source `.bashrc` from `.profile`. See @DanRabinowitz's answer.

Comment: At least not unconditionally.

Comment: `[ -n "$BASH" -a -f ~/.bashrc ] && . ~/.bashrc` would be a sweet oneliner for `.profile`.

Comment: @nyuszika7h, Why not? [Everyone  seems](https://archive.is/sl9sC#selection-885.5-897.1) to suggest doing so.