# Changed "path" variable in Ubuntu Linux and basic commands have stopped working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, path, gnome-terminal

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (as a virtual machine). I installed TeX Live system over the internet.
Once the installation of TeX live finished, it said

```
Most importantly, add /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux
to your PATH for current and future sessions.
```

So, I typed the following command in the terminal.

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux
```

It didn't throw any error or did not ask any questions / confirmation.

When I tried to run `clear` command on the terminal it said

```
Command 'clear' is available in '/usr/bin/clear'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
clear: command not found
```

What have I done wrong? and more importantly how do it fix it?

*However if I close the terminal and re open the terminal, everything seems to be normal. Now will TeX live work?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've temporarily redefined where your system looks to find important commands.

What you want is this:

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
```

That redefines $PATH as the textlive directory AND what $PATH was before.

Re-open your terminal and the re-assignment will be lost, so everything is back to normal.

To update the $PATH permanently, add the line to ~/.profile (or ~/.bash_profile if you only want it to affect bash.)

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path and [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980)

Comment: should I make this as a permanent change to work with TeX live? Because, it seems to work even after restarting the terminal. So I don't understand the `Most importantly, add /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux  to your PATH for current and future sessions.` message shown during the installation

Comment: I have edited my answer with information about doing that.

Comment: @Prasanna Notice the **add** in `Most importantly, ADD /usr/local/te...`  Add it to the path. Not replace thew old path with a new.

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make though!

Comment: @Prasanna The PATH variable contains all the paths which will be searched by the terminal when you type a command. E.g., if you type "echo hello," the terminal doesn't just magically know where 'echo' is located, it will actually search through each directory in your path until it finds an executable named 'echo.' The installation instructions tell you to add texlive to your PATH so that you can access the files in that folder without having to type out the entire folder name. You are supposed to *add* that directory to your PATH, not replace your PATH entirely.