# Ubuntu color text in terminal not showing up unless I run

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ssh, terminal

I am using a droplet (vps) from digital ocean, and when I first got it and logged in the text was colorized automatically, I must have changed something to make it not colorized, now I have to either run `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.profile` everytime I ssh into the droplet.

I also uncommented `force_color_prompt=yes` in the `~/.bashrc` and the problem persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general Bash sources some files on startup; the details depend on how it was invoked. See [*Bash Startup Files*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files). Solely by reading this documentation one cannot really tell how exactly an SSH server (or your SSH server) invokes `bash`, so it's not immediately obvious which set of startup files is used.

Usually (and most likely in your case) one gets an interactive [login](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46856/108618) shell and this fragment of the documentation applies:

> Invoked as an interactive login shell, or with `--login`
>
> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The `--noprofile` option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior. […]

There is another fragment titled "Invoked by remote shell daemon" but my tests indicate it applies to a situation when one runs a shell command (as opposed to an interactive shell) via SSH.

My hypothesis is you created `~/.bash_profile` and/or `~/.bash_login`, therefore `~/.profile` is no longer "the first one that exists and is readable". Your `~/.profile` probably detects Bash and sources `~/.bashrc` (verify this) and the coloring is defined in the latter file.

Ask yourself if you need `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`; maybe what you put there could (or should) be somewhere else. Please read [*Difference between `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`*](https://superuser.com/a/183980/432690).

If you really need `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` then make it source `~/.profile` maybe; or make it conditionally source `~/.bashrc` like your `~/.profile` supposably does.

What to run and what to source in what order from what file should be your informed decision. I cannot give you more detailed hint because I don't know what you put in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` nor what you tried to achieve. I only suspect one of these files prevents `~/.profile` (and thus `~/.bashrc`, indirectly) from being sourced at startup.

Answer (score 0):

Appending to `.bash_profile` this:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
. ~/.bashrc
fi
```

It definitely fixed for me.

It can be done in one line:

```
cat <<EOT >> ~/.bash_profile
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
. ~/.bashrc
fi
EOT
```